# проблема с возвратом переменной в C# из хранимой процедуры mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

есть хранимая процедура в БД mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
    USE `myschema`$$
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_max_update`(in p_id,int, out v_index int)
    BEGIN
      select max(id) into v_index
      from updates
      where id=p_id;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

пытаюсь вызвать её из C#

```
private int getMaxUpdate(int id)
        {
        string conn_str = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=myschema;Uid=myschema_user;Pwd=Qwerty12345;OPTION=3;";
        OdbcConnection oconn = new OdbcConnection();
        oconn.ConnectionString = conn_str;
        OdbcCommand ocmd = new OdbcCommand();
        ocmd.Connection = oconn;
        ocmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        ocmd.CommandText = "call get_max_update(?,?)";
        OdbcParameter op;

        op = new OdbcParameter();
        op.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        op.ParameterName = "@p_id";
        op.OdbcType = OdbcType.Int;
        op.Value = id;
        ocmd.Parameters.Add(op);


        op = new OdbcParameter();
        op.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        op.ParameterName = "@v_index";
        op.OdbcType = OdbcType.Int;
        op.Value = 0;
        ocmd.Parameters.Add(op);

        oconn.Open();

        ocmd.ExecuteScalar();

        oconn.Close();

        return Convert.ToInt32(ocmd.Parameters["@v_index"].Value);
    }
```

Но при вызове вылазит эксепшн

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
```

Прошу помочь разобраться, или подсказать как правильно вызывать хранимую процедуру с параметрами IN и OUT.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int getMaxUpdate(int id)
{
    string outValue = "";
    string conn_str = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=myschema;Uid=myschema_user;Pwd=Qwerty12345;OPTION=3;";

    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conn_str))
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("get_max_update", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_id", id);

        //затем вставляем результат эксикьюта в дата тейбл
        using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                outValue = dt.Rows[0]["v_index"].toString();
            }else
            {
                outValue = "0";
            }
        }
    }

    return Convert.ToInt32(outValue);
}
```

В случае если в результате эксикьюта вашей хранимой процедуры не будет возвращено никаких значений, то ваша функция вернет значение 0.
Отладку ошибок делать не стал ибо данный код - пример запуска хранимой процедуры с базы mysql.